# find the pom.xml of a web application that is deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, pom.xml

I have a bunch of web applications that are deployed in tomcat. I want to find the pom.xml file for these applications. Is there a way I can find the pom.xml from these applications without checking out the source code on my machine and checking it out that way. I know that I can see all my properties files and web.xml files. But, can't find the pom.xml file. I used mvn package to create the war files. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the generated WAR, take a look at `META-INF\maven\${project.groupId}\${project.artifactId}\` folder, like the image:

[image: pom.xml in WAR file]

For this WAR, `${project.groupId}` is `com.brunocesar` and `${project.artifactId}` is `springmvc-sample`

Check if pom file is there.

Answer (score 1):

Packaging the war file won't include the pom.xml - there's really no need for it to be there.  If you really want to include the pom.xml inside the war, you can have [maven include it as a resource.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)